# Асинхронная загрузка JQuery?

Tags: jquery, асинхронность, google-speed-test

*Google SpeedTest* просит, чтобы не было в коде блокирующего загрузок js, и использовались async и defer.

Но у меня по чему то при использование этих тегов *JQuery* скрпты напрочь отказываются работать после добавления этих тегов. В чем может быть проблема?

```
<head> 
    <script async type="text/javascript" src="/template/js/jquery.js"></script> 
</head>
```

Comment: Что значит "отказываются"? Марш несогласных с оптимизацией?

Comment: Хотя, видимо, Вы пытаетесь работать с хуквери до её загрузки. Раньше была синхронная загрузка, а теперь...

Comment: Самое простое решение в данной ситуации это поменять async на defer.

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/post/323790/

Answer (score 1):

Причина в том что jquery должен использоватся так, как его рекомендуют использовать. К примеру можно использовать с помощью официальных cdn. В вашем случае с async происходит догрузка jquery после того как он востребован "во всех ваших скриптах". А нужно его грузить до того как мы его пишем в своем коде. Рекомендация использовать код в начале `<head>`:

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

для jquery не нужно использовать async но даже если вы используете его, то свой код в большинстве случаев нужно заворачивать в это. Мне кажется вы этого не сделали.

```
$(document).ready(function (){
//код
});
```

Будет вызывать ваш код после того как страница готова. async собственно подгружает асинхронно скрипты. И async обычно используют для второстепенных скриптов а также больших скриптов, например для отрисовки сложых эллементов баннерной рекламы. Можете просмотреть любые 10 интернет магазинов которые знаете. Думаю что ни один не использует async для первостепенных библиотек таких как jquery. async нужно использовать для тяжелых скриптов, время загрузки и выполнения которых для нас не критично (что ни как не совпадает с целями использования jquery). Нужно использовать CDN, если нужна оптимизация.

Comment: В том то и дело что мой код использующий JQuery завернут в

$(document).ready(function (){
//код
});

CDN итак используется (CloudFlare).

Необходимость в добавление этого атрибута возникла исключительно с точки зрения SEO,

гугл выше ранжирует те сайты которые по его мнению быстро загружаются. И в своем гуглТесте у него по сути единственная претензия к моему сайту - как раз таки в том что якобы jquery не ассинхронно загружается, и тем самым блокирует быструю загрузку всей страницы.

Comment: Лучше все же перед закрывающим тегом head, ну и разумеется до других скриптов использующих jQuery. В моем конкретном случае страничка начинает прорисовываться раньше чем если я положу его в начало.